# Data not rendering after returning from Firestore onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am using an Ionic/Angular frontend here. My data comes back from Firestore correctly. It also comes back after a change has been made to the firestore document.

However, the data never renders to the `ion-content`. It does log to the console correctly. This leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with Ionic/Angular.

The template file

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="!this.isLoading">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let team of currentTeams; let index" [color]="team.color" style="margin: 10px;">
      <p>{{index}}</p>
      <h1 slot="start" style="height: 3.5rem;">{{ team.name }}</h1>
      <br />
      <div id="controls" slot="end">
        <ion-icon style="margin: 0 20px" name="remove-circle" (click)="decrementTeamScore(team)"></ion-icon>
        <span>{{ team.score }}</span>
        <ion-icon style="margin: 0 20px" name="add-circle" (click)="incrementTeamScore(team)"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

The class file

```
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.gameId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    if(this.gameId) {
      const result = await this.getGame();
      if(result) {
        await this.getTeams();
      }
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
  public async getTeams() {
    const teamRef = this.teamsCollection.ref;
    const teamsByGameIdQuery = teamRef.where('gameId', '==', this.currentGame.docID).orderBy('score', 'desc');
    onSnapshot(teamsByGameIdQuery, (snapshot) => {
      const teams: ITeam[] = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        teams.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        this.currentTeams = teams;
      });
      console.log(this.currentTeams);
    });
  }
```

Also including the console data that I am getting back from Firestore.
[image: Console Data]

And here is a screenshot of the current screen
[image: Picture of current screen]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see, always this errors cames to me, I just remove HTML tags (p, hr, div) and use Ionic own components, like ion-title, ion-card, and so on.

Find more on https://ionicframework.com/docs/components

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks I will check it out and update my question if I can get more clarity on my issue. One extra thing I came to find out, and I will add this to my original post, is that it renders if I come from another page but if I stay on this page and hit the refresh button it doesn't render with the data